# How to put 2 containers into 1 container in java?

Tags: java, swing

My class has 4 parts of textfields, 1 on the top, 1 on the left, 2 on the right. As I am using containers, so I think I need to put those 2 together under 1 big container so that I can set it's location in "East", but I'm not sure how...

```
private void display1(Container container){
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints constraint = new GridBagConstraints();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
    display1 = new JTextField("testing");
    constraint.gridx = 4;
    constraint.gridy = 0;
    panel.add(displaytrain, constraint);
    container.add(panel);
}

private void display2(Container container){
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints constraint = new GridBagConstraints();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
    display2 = new JTextField("testing");
    constraint.gridx = 4;
    constraint.gridy = 0;
    panel.add(displaytrain, constraint);
    container.add(panel);
}
private void bigDisplay(Container container){
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints constraint = new GridBagConstraints();
    //putting the dispay1 and display2 here...?
    container.add(panel, "East");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to insert display1 () and 2 into the created panel in bigDisplay?

If so, in each displayX, instead of  adding to the container the panel you created, just return it and add it on bigDisplay to the created panel there

```
private JPanel display1(){
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints constraint = new GridBagConstraints();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
    display1 = new JTextField("testing");
    constraint.gridx = 4;
    constraint.gridy = 0;
    panel.add(display1, constraint);
    return panel;
}

private JPanel display2(){
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints constraint = new GridBagConstraints();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
    display2 = new JTextField("testing");
    constraint.gridx = 4;
    constraint.gridy = 0;
    panel.add(display2, constraint);
    return panel;
}
private void bigDisplay(Container container){
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
    GridBagConstraints constraint = new GridBagConstraints();
    panel.add (display1 (), constraint);
    panel.add (display2 (), constraint);
    container.add(panel, "East");
}
```

Comment: Instead of void just write JPanel

Comment: @HuiTingKo- I have added code to my answer. Review it.

Comment: I think you need `panel.add (display1 (container), constraint);`

Comment: You are adding the panel in bigDisplay to the container at the end.

Comment: now they are in the same box but they shown next to each other, is there anyway that display 1 shown in first line and display 2 shown in the next line?

Comment: Add panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1)); to the panel in bigDisplay